# ESP8266 always resetting after 65 second of running

Tags: esp8266, arduino-ide, reset

I have a simple code where ESP8266 is asking MySQL database about actual state of LED (whether 1 or 0) and when DB has 1 ESP8266 turns LED on... But my problem is after 65-66 seconds of server running is still resetting... The program does what it is supposed to do, but after 65-66 seconds resets and trying to reconnecting to wifi

---- EDIT -----

After some experiments with code I have found, it doesn't matter the running time but, number of loop cycles... Every time no matter on delay or processing speed, it crash after 48 cycles....

.ino code

```
// Load Wi-Fi library
#include <ESP8266WiFi.h>
#include <WiFiClient.h> 
#include <ESP8266WebServer.h>
#include <ESP8266HTTPClient.h>

// Replace with your network credentials
const char* ssid     = "XXXX";
const char* password = "XXXX";
const char* host = "http://www.XXXX.XX/arduino_PHP/post_data.php"; 

// Set web server port number to 80
WiFiServer server(80);
HTTPClient http; 

// Variable to store the HTTP request
String header;

// Auxiliar variables to store the current output state
String output5State = "off";
String output4State = "off";

// Assign output variables to GPIO pins
const int output5 = 5;
const int output4 = 4;
byte green, red= 0;

void setup() {
 Serial.begin(115200);
 // Initialize the output variables as outputs
  WiFi.mode(WIFI_OFF);        //Prevents reconnection issue (taking too long to connect)
  WiFi.mode(WIFI_STA);        //This line hides the viewing of ESP as wifi hotspot
 delay(1000);
 pinMode(output5, OUTPUT);
 pinMode(output4, OUTPUT);
 // Set outputs to LOW
 digitalWrite(output5, LOW);
 digitalWrite(output4, LOW);

 // Connect to Wi-Fi network with SSID and password
 Serial.print("Connecting to ");
 Serial.println(ssid);
 WiFi.begin(ssid, password);
 while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED) {
   delay(500);
   Serial.print(".");
 }
 // Print local IP address and start web server
 Serial.println("");
 Serial.println("WiFi connected.");
 Serial.println("IP address: ");
 Serial.println(WiFi.localIP());
 server.begin();
}

void loop(){
delay(500);
DB_state("Green",green);
DB_state("Red",red);
delay(500);
}

void DB_state(String component,int state){
 String postData =("component=" + String(component) + "&state=" + String(state));
 Serial.println(postData);
  http.begin("http://www.XXXX.XX/arduino_PHP/DB_state.php"); 
  http.addHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
 http.POST(postData);   //Send the request
 String payload = http.getString();    //Get the response payload
 Serial.println(payload);
 http.end();  //Close connection
 state_LED(payload,component);
 }

void state_LED(String str, String led){ 
 int x; 
   if (led== "Green") {
     x = 4;}
   else if (led== "Red") {
      x = 5;}
   if (str == "State: 1") {
     digitalWrite(x, HIGH);}
   else if (str == "State: 0") {
     digitalWrite(x, LOW);}
 }
```

ESP8266 Stack debug

```
Exception 28: LoadProhibited: A load referenced a page mapped with an attribute that does not permit loads
PC: 0x4020744a: ClientContext::state() const at C:\Users\XXXX\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\esp8266\hardware\esp8266\2.7.4\libraries\ESP8266WiFi\src/include/ClientContext.h line 364
EXCVADDR: 0x00000184

Decoding stack results
0x40203f10: HardwareSerial::write(unsigned char const*, unsigned int) at C:\Users\XXXX\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\esp8266\hardware\esp8266\2.7.4\cores\esp8266/HardwareSerial.h line 164
0x40203f1c: HardwareSerial::write(unsigned char const*, unsigned int) at C:\Users\XXXX\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\esp8266\hardware\esp8266\2.7.4\cores\esp8266/HardwareSerial.h line 165
0x40207512: HTTPClient::connected() at C:\Users\XXXX\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\esp8266\hardware\esp8266\2.7.4\libraries\ESP8266HTTPClient\src\ESP8266HTTPClient.cpp line 475
0x40202d24: HTTPClient::disconnect(bool) at C:\Users\XXXX\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\esp8266\hardware\esp8266\2.7.4\libraries\ESP8266HTTPClient\src\ESP8266HTTPClient.cpp line 434
0x40203ac8: HTTPClient::end() at C:\Users\XXXX\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\esp8266\hardware\esp8266\2.7.4\libraries\ESP8266HTTPClient\src\ESP8266HTTPClient.cpp line 425
0x402012ba: DB_State(String, int) at C:\Users\XXXX\Documents\Arduino\ESP8266_php_DB_control/ESP8266_php_DB_control.ino line 87
0x40201334: loop() at C:\Users\XXXX\Documents\Arduino\ESP8266_php_DB_control/ESP8266_php_DB_control.ino line 73
0x40100175: esp_schedule() at C:\Users\XXXX\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\esp8266\hardware\esp8266\2.7.4\cores\esp8266\core_esp8266_main.cpp line 125
0x40205628: loop_wrapper() at C:\Users\XXXX\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\esp8266\hardware\esp8266\2.7.4\cores\esp8266\core_esp8266_main.cpp line 197
```

Thanks for any advice

Comment: So it might be a memory issue like a leak or resource allocation problem.

Comment: I thought so, but how fix it?

Comment: Before you can fix it, you need to identify it. Read the documentation of `WiFiServer` and `HTTPClient`, use your web search skills on the detailed error message of "exception 28", and so on. Check your findings and assumptions with test programs; for example, call `http.POST()` twice in `DB_state()` and count the numbers of loops.

Comment: as first I would stop using String

Comment: Why? And how you replace it?

Comment: @Juraj pozdravujem slovenského brata v programovaní :D :D :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know how, but finally I have found working solution... I have add `HTTPClient http;` at top of function and it works...

```
void DB_state(String component,int state){
HTTPClient http; // THIS IS ADDED
 String postData =("component=" + String(component) + "&state=" + String(state));
 Serial.println(postData);
  http.begin("http://www.XXXX.XX/arduino_PHP/DB_state.php"); 
  http.addHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
 http.POST(postData);   //Send the request
 String payload = http.getString();    //Get the response payload
 Serial.println(payload);
 http.end();  //Close connection
 state_LED(payload,component);
 }
```

Can anyone explain me how it's possible? Because I don't fully understand this procedure.

Comment: You now construct and destruct the `HTTPClient` object in that scope each time, as [C++ specifies](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/storage_duration#Storage_duration). Presumably the global one leaks some sort of resource, but I can only speculate on that front.

Comment: Sorry, i don't understand. Could you be more simlier?

Comment: I can't break this down any further in the space provided to me by a comment. I suggest taking a tutorial on C++ that covers objects, constructors, destructors, and such, which will provide this info in a far cleaner way. But basically, instead of having one HTTPClient for the lifetime of the program, you create a new HTTPClient and clean it up after each request -- This makes sense intuitively, but I don't know the internals of HTTPClient enough to know why it happens to eventually crash if you reuse the same instance over and over again.

Comment: https://github.com/esp8266/Arduino/issues/7613#issuecomment-700782051